# Image background color bleeding on circular image

Tags: javascript, css

I have a circular image (a profile picture). This image may or may not be translucent so I've given it a background color to ensure that it's always visible. The problem I'm having is that the background color is visible even on images that are completely opaque (see figures).

After messing around with borders and padding I found a workaround. I found that adding an invisible border, and then removing it will fix the problem. To deal with images being dynamically added and removed, I do this on a timer (this was easier than injecting some code in all places where images are added to the page). This is what I've done and it seems to work but I don't like it.

```
setInterval(() => {
  for (const img of document.getElementsByTagName("img")) {
    if (img.style.border.length) {
      img.style.border = "";
    } else {
      img.style.border = "0 solid transparent";
    }
  }
}, 500);
```

The `<img>` has the `width` and `height` attributes set to `32`. It also has a `border-radius` of `16px` and of course, a `background-color`.

Surely there must be a better way to deal with this than the `setInterval` above. Changing the border seems to be causing the element to be rendered again (and correctly). Perhaps there's a way to do this more directly?

Since this is a weird rendering issue, I should mention that I'm using **Chrome 87**.

I found another workaround that's a little bit more efficient. Whenever an image is added to the page, I attached an onload listener that updates the border.

```
img.onload = () => {
  setTimeout(() => img.style.border = "0 solid transparent", 100);
};
```

This still feels like an ugly hack. Also, the edge around the image appears briefly before disappearing when the page loads. I'm looking for a better way.

I tried this out in Safari and updating the border doesn't help. It seems like I'll need to think outside the box.

---

[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 1 - disgusting**

---

[image: Figure 2]

**Figure 2 - desired**

Comment: Can you share any one of those images on a sandbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh neat, what an interesting issue! Unfortunately I've looked and looked and looked and can't seem to see *why* this is happening. Triggering a reflow of *any* kind seems to fix it though, so whether you use the border or not should work.

However I think I've found another solution that would work without requiring a reflow, and that's using a *radial-gradient* `background-image` instead of a solid background color.

I set up an example pen here: https://codepen.io/xhynk/pen/ZEprxqq (it was easy to increment the `?4` to uncache the image and get it to "act weird" again.

Using this CSS for the background on the image, it seems to prevent the image from being close enough to "bleed" through the edge:

```
img {
    background-image: radial-gradient(#000 70%, transparent calc(70% + 1px));
}
```

You could potentially drop the `70%` down to `69%` if you're still seeing it. I just tried to get it as close to the edge of the container as possible, and the +1px calc smooths it out instead of being jagged.

You can see in the following image, the first avatar has the `radial-gradient` applied and there's no bleed, and the second has the solid `background: black` instead which does.

[image: image of bg bleeding through]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate what you just told. And it seems to work just fine.

From what I understood, I am thinking of one possible error that is to replace fixed width of the image and set it to 100% and not care about the height of the image in the `img` tag.

Set the height and width of the image in your surrounding div and give that a background color.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
#image-container {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background: lightseagreen;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="image-container">
  <img src="img_avatar.png"/>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Just copy paste it into https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic to see

Comment: I copied your answer to w3schools and clicked the Run button. The background color is bleeding (**Figure 1**). If I click the Run button again (without doing anything else!), the problem is resolved (**Figure 2**).

Comment: @IndianaKernick Can confirm. In Chromium the edge disappears on the second execution, in FF it just stays there.